# Give Jersey access to CSS & JS files

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey to serve up a JSP file (this may not be the best way to do this, feel free to suggest alternatives)

At the moment I have a resource which I'm using like:

```
@Path("/home")
public class HomeResource{
    @GET
    public Viewable getView() {     
        return new Viewable("/home");
    }
}
```

The trouble is home.jsp depends on a style file Home_style.css and there isnt a Jersey endpoint to cater for this so a browser can't access it. I could do something like:

```
public class HomeResource{
    @GET
    @Path("/home")
    public Viewable getView() {     
        return new Viewable("/home");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/home_style")
    public Viewable getStyle() {        
        return new Viewable("/home_style");
    }
}
```

But I'd rather not create endpoints for every css or javascript file I depend on. Is there a way I can provide a browser with access to these types of files without needing to cater for it in my java code?

---

Project Layout

- src/main/java/HomeResource.java
- Web-Inf/home.jsp
- Web-Inf/home_style.css
- Web-Inf/web.xml

Answer (score 1):

put your static files outside of webapplication probably hosted in webserver say apache.In your html give direct url not relative paths 
So app server may host jersey resources in http://www.mybackendsite.com/myawsomerestservice/rest/*
your web server http://www.mycustomerfacing.com/index.html
in html all refer to http://www.mycustomerfacing.com/css/* http://www.mycustomerfacing.com/js/* where it is hosted
This way you create seperation of concern and cleaner code to deploy backend and frontend.